# sicp counting change exericse

Tags: ruby, sicp

I am working on the counting change algorithm found in the SICP book. I am trying to get it right in Ruby. First, I had trouble with syntax failing now, it has turned into an infinite loop

```
irb(main):001:0> count_change(5)
```

SystemStackError: stack level too deep
    from .../.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/irb/workspace.rb:86
Maybe IRB bug!

I thought it would be a good time to use StackOverflow. It will help out a lot if you can help. I think the problem is on line 12.
Thanks.

```
def count_change amount
  cc(amount, 5)
end

def cc(amount, kinds_of_coins)
  if amount == 0
    1
  elsif amount < 0 || kinds_of_coins == 0
    0
  else
    cc amount, (kinds_of_coins - 1) + 
        cc((amount - (first_denomination(kinds_of_coins))), kinds_of_coins)
  end
end

def first_denomination(kinds_of_coins)
  if kinds_of_coins == 1
    1
  elsif kinds_of_coins == 2
    5
  elsif kinds_of_coins == 3
    10
  elsif kinds_of_coins == 4
    25
  elsif kinds_of_coins == 5
    50
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in this line:

```
cc amount, (kinds_of_coins - 1) + 
    cc((amount - (first_denomination(kinds_of_coins))), kinds_of_coins)
```

Which is actually

```
cc(amount, 
 (kinds_of_coins - 1) + cc((amount - (first_denomination(kinds_of_coins))), kinds_of_coins))
```

when `amount` is 5 and `kinds_of_coins` is 2 `(amount - (first_denomination(kinds_of_coins)))` returns `0`, which means that `cc(0, anything)` returns `1` - and the next recursion is `cc(5, 2)` again...

I'm not familiar with the SICP algorithm but I suspect what you *meant* to write was

```
cc(amount, (kinds_of_coins - 1)) + 
    cc((amount - (first_denomination(kinds_of_coins))), kinds_of_coins)
```